# How do interrupts work on multicore ARM cpu

Tags: arm, multicore, interrupt

This question has already been answered for x86 however, I couldn't find much about ARM MP cpus like Cortex-A9, Cortex-A15 etc...

More importantly i want to know if interrupts can be raised on non-primary cpu without any configuration etc.

I am working on a software which deals only with the primary cpu hence i put the rest in WFI state however I am unaware of how interrupts work on the MP arm cpus, Is it possible that the main cpu continues executing code and one of the secondary cpu picks it up and jumps to the instruction in vector table and execute that code ?

btw here is the code I'm using to put them to low power mode

```
    uint32_t reg;

    __asm__ volatile("mrc p15, 0, %0, c0, c0, 5" : "=r" (reg));
    reg &= 0xF;

    if(reg > 0)
        goto spin;

<code snipped>

spin:
    for(;;)
        cpu_idle(); // cpu_idle -> wfi
```

Comment: have you looked at the ARM ARM and TRM for the mpcore?

Comment: Yes, it does mention few things about GIC and how IPI work but nothing about how general interrupts are scheduled.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The short and for practical purposes correct answer is that what you ask for is not possible without some configuration being performed on the secondary cores...

The interrupt controller architecture is described (in quite some detail) in http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ihi0048b/index.html

To prepare the secondary cores to receive IPIs, you need to:

- Enable the GIC Distributor (once, for the whole system)
- Enable the GIC CPU interface (for each core)
- Enable the IPIs you want to receive (for each core)
- Set the priorities for each IPI you want to receive (for each core)
- Ensure the CPU interface Interrupt Priority Mask Register (for each core) is set to priority level lower (higher number) than the interrupt priority you set above.
- Clear the CPSR I-bit (for each core)

If you don't intend to implement an interrupt handler, skip the clearing of the I-bit. The core will come out of WFI and continue executing. That is normally what you want for a system boot operation.

Comment: As for distributing interrupts to non-primary cores, the Interrupt Processor Targets Registers specify which cores receive each of the shared peripheral interrupts.

Comment: so unless i explicitly clear the I bit in CPSR of the secondary cores, interrupts will be masked and WFI should keep them in low power mode forever right ? also does WFE wake core on an interrupt ? so if a software after my own boots will it be able to wake up those cores from WFI ? Hence I'm thinking of using WFE but on a uniprocessor we don't have any other core to send a signal if we're in WFE so just want to make sure if interrupt wakes core from WFE

Comment: Nopes. What the I bit does is prevents the interrupt from being taken (switch mode/jump to vector). With the I bit set the core will still come out of low-power state, but it will just continue executing the instruction after WFI in the program.

Yes, interrupts also wake up cores in WFE. But if you're thinking of using SEV/WFE as a replacement for IPIs, you need to consider the fact of non-guaranteed delivery.

Comment: Hmmm, so you're saying if interrupts are disabled on secondary cores and they're in WFI, it is possible for them to leave that state ? How ?

Comment: If interrupts are enabled in the GIC, but masked in the CPSR, an interrupt being signalled is still a "wakeup event" - both for WFI and WFE.